# MikroTik DHCP server sends wrong DNS server

Tags: dns, dhcp

I have a MikroTik (10.0.0.138) router, where the static DNS server 8.8.8.8 is set and DHCP is enabled. The configuration of the MikroTik is:

[image]

To my understanding, when the MikroTik answers a DHCP request, it should send itself (10.0.0.138) as DNS server to enable caching, so that clients do not directly contact 8.8.8.8, correct? But on the client side, resolvectl status prints:

```
Link 2 (enp4s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
```

instead of 10.0.0.138. With tcpdump I see:

```
2024-02-02 22:16:30.715260 78:9a:18:7b:62:db > a8:a1:59:66:d9:a2, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x0, ttl 16, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    10.0.0.138.67 > 10.0.0.1.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0xf4ee565e, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-IP 10.0.0.1
      Your-IP 10.0.0.1
      Server-IP 10.0.0.138
      Client-Ethernet-Address a8:a1:59:66:d9:a2
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message (53), length 1: ACK
        Server-ID (54), length 4: 10.0.0.138
        Lease-Time (51), length 4: 600
        Subnet-Mask (1), length 4: 255.255.255.0
        Default-Gateway (3), length 4: 10.0.0.138
        Domain-Name-Server (6), length 4: 8.8.8.8
```

Is this a misunderstanding of the way DNS works or a misconfiguration? Your comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: You should show your DHCP configuration to troubleshoot what DNS servers are configured to be advertised to clients.  If your router is configured as a DNS server/resolver, you would want to advertise its address as the DNS through DHCP.

Comment: @GracefulRestart, I was focussed on the DNS settings, but had to make the setting in DHCP Server -> Networks. It works now, thank you!